# Dataverse: "Network error when using Patch function: You don't have permission to create this row."

Tags: dataverse

I created a power app, the power app is based on dataverse. I have three tables, the main table is Small Equipment, and Hire Records, Equipment image as the child tables, one-many relationship, the security role is Basic Users, and I grant the permissions like this: Parent: Child Business Unit for create, read, write, delete, append,append to.

I can create new records in Small Equipment table, add picture in Image table, and add new records in Hire records table in TEST environment, but when I import to PROD envrionment, same permissions for basic user, the basic user can not add image in image table, the other two table is good, the error is "Network error when using Patch function: You don't have permission to create this row.", anyone can help me?

And when I use the monitor function for the power app, the similar is "User with ID XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX does not have Create permissions for the XXXX_itemid attribute in the XXXX_XXXX_itemimages entity. Count secured attributes in entity 1. User has 0 secured attribute privileges. callerAp=null"

Comment: you should double check the permissions in PROD, because the error is pretty clear

Comment: @GuidoPreite, can you give some more advisor? as I check the Security Role for the Basic User, "Parent: Child Business Units" for all three tables both in PROD and TEST, it works in TEST, but not in PROD

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be either because of the missing create permission in the table or because user does not have required field security profile and there is atleast 1 secure field in the table.

> Count secured attributes in entity 1. User has 0 secured attribute privileges. callerAp=null"

Comment: Thank you @Harinarayanan, the error is because of the different configuration between different environments